# i tried to run the code in dart pad, online platform

Tags: dart

**dart:**

As you can see in this .dart code I am trying to print the list of **id**, there is a Dummy Data class which have a list of details of some product. There is a main function which call a instance (productIdList)  of a class name **Present**.

```
 class DummyData{
      List<Product> dummyProduct = [
         Product(
        id: 'p1',
        title: 'Red Shirt',
        description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
        price: 29.99,
        imageUrl:
            'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
      ),
      Product(
        id: 'p2',
        title: 'Trousers',
        description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
        price: 59.99,
        imageUrl:
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
      ),
      Product(
        id: 'p3',
        title: 'Yellow Scarf',
        description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
        price: 19.99,
        imageUrl: 'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
      ),
      Product(
        id: 'p4',
        title: 'A Pan',
        description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
        price: 49.99,
        imageUrl:
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
      ),
      ];
    }
    class Product{
      final String id;
      final String title;
      final String description;
      final double price;
      final String imageUrl;
      
      Product({this.id, this.description, this.imageUrl, this.price, this.title});
    }
    
    class Present extends DummyData{
      void productIdList (){
        print(dummyProduct.map((product) =>product.id).toList());
      }
    }
    
    void main(){
      Present obj = Present();
      obj.productIdList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above will not compile in the latest version of dart due to changes made to support null safety. Specifically the product class. You can fix in a few different ways.

The first approach would be to mark all of the constructor arguments in the `Product` class as required. This approach makes it so you have to pass in values for every constructor argument.

```dart
class Product {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;

  Product(
      {required this.id,
      required this.description,
      required this.imageUrl,
      required this.price,
      required this.title});
}
```

The other approach would be to make the fields within the product class nullable. In this approach, you are not required to pass in a value for every constructor argument, but when you do not pass in a value the field will be assigned a `null` value.

```dart
class Product {
  final String? id;
  final String? title;
  final String? description;
  final double? price;
  final String? imageUrl;

  Product(
      {this.id,
      this.description,
      this.imageUrl,
      this.price,
      this.title});
}
```